# Over the air OS update via eclipse hawkbit for our IoT edge devices is yelding an error status but enough information about the error

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

I have been using eclipse hawkbit over the air updater to update our IoT fleet of devices. In many cases the update fails and gives and error status, but through out the UI there are not enough information about the error it self, why it happened and what cause it. Could you please suggest me a solution or a better way to check the error message so I can evaluate better what happened and the the update failed? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6UxS.png)

I tried to run the upload in different times and I expected that it could be a connectivity issue but I checked other platforms and connection status of the devices could be week or unstable but not completely offline.

So what I really need, is to know more details about the failure and the error message.